# InfoPath 2010 File Attachment error

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-foundation

I am having an issue with InfoPath 2010, I am getting the below error when adding a file Attachment control and a Person/Group Picker, when adding File Attachment control, the file is attached to the form with no error, but when i add a person/Group picker to the form along with File Attachment control i get the below error, i have set the customError tag in web.config to "Off" but i still get this error with no details, i need to know what cause this error and why it appears when i have person/group picker added to the form!
I have read that setting Web Page Security Validation to Off will solve this issue and it solved it but when setting Web Page Security Validation  to off i get

`An unhandled exception has occurred in silverlight Application`
Please Help!!!

please help!

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent long time to figure out what was the problem and how to solve it, finally i came up with the below:

i have to change the "FormServer.aspx" file located under LAYOUTS folder in 14 hive, and added the line

```
<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server"/>
```

after

```
<body runat="server" id="PageBody">
```

Now Attachments are working fine ;)